# types of expressions in operator ?(expression 1):(expression 2) in Java

Tags: java, operator-keyword

I met a problem, code like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "1";
        String str2 = "2";
        String str3 = "3";
        boolean flag = true;

        // way 1
        test(flag? str1, str2, str3: str1); 

        // way 2
        test(flag? (str1, str2, str3): str1);

        // way 3
        test(flag? new String[]{str1, str2, str3}: str1);

        // way 4
        test(flag? new String[]{str1, str2, str3}: new String[]{str1});

        // way 5
        test(flag? str1: str2);  
    }

    private static void test(String... args) {
        for(String arg: args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
```

}

I used five ways to call method test():

way 1  called failed. I thought I missed the parentheses.

way 2  failed. I thought it's the problem of (str1, str2, str3), Java compiler didn't understand it.

way 3  failed. new String[]{} is a String[] object, why Java compiler still didn't understand it?

way 4  successfully. the left and right parameter of colon is the same type. So, I called it in way 5.

way 5  called successfully.

I guessed:

```
     ?(1):(2), the parameters in place 1 and 2 must be the same type？
```

Can anyone who have a good understanding of operator :? solve my confusion? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like people really didn't understand your question, you might want to edit it.

Anyway here is my answer:

Method 1 & Method 2: syntax doesn't make sense, you're asking the compiler to do something it cannot. A ternary experssion must look like this:

```
value = condition ? expression : expression
```

a comma is not an operator in java and the compiler expects exactly that, an operator.

Method 3: fails because both possible results of a ternary expression must have the same type. Which is why Method 4 works fine.

Method 5: compiles fine, but will not work because your constructor expects an array still.

EDIT: I should also mention that if your condition validates false, Method 4 will also fail with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but that's trivial to your question.

Comment: it's the answer I want. test(String...) need a variable length parameters, can I say like this: test(object) and object = flag? expression1: expression2, that's why both expressions must return the same type.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = condition ? "pass" : "fail";
```

Is shorthand for:

```
String a;
if ( condition ) {
  a = "pass";
} else {
  a = "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called the "ternary operator". More info here:
[?: on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Usually the ternary operator in java is allowed to return different types of values depending on the condition. This is a valid expression in java:

```
int anInteger = 1;
String aString = "a";

System.out.println(true ? anInteger : aString);
System.out.println(false ? anInteger : aString);
```

with an output of:

```
1
a
```

On the other hand, in your piece of code the returned value is being passed as argument to the test method which takes String... as a parameter. So the returned value should match that type.

Comment: OP asked about ternary operators. Elvis operators are shorthand for ternary operators where you do not specify the true condition, (false ?: aString).

Comment: What you are saying is true though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have a deep understanding. But I will try to explain anyway.

?: operator is basically used to simplify the if else expression

```
if (a > b) {
  c = a;
}
else {
  c = b;
}
```

This can be written as `c = (a > b) ? a : b;`

Now,in way 1

```
test(flag? str1, str2, str3: str1);
```

The compiler fails because it is expecting a : instead of the , after str1 which is why it fails.

Now in way 2

```
test(flag? (str1, str2, str3): str1);
```

(str1,str2,str3) is not a valid object. You have to create an array to store a set of strings. Simply bundling them up in () wont work.

Way 3

```
test(flag? new String[]{str1, str2, str3}: str1);
```

Now I believe the reason for this failing is because test expects a string array output but str1 is only a string.

Way 4

```
test(flag? new String[]{str1, str2, str3}: new String[]{str1});
```

This executes successfully but merely switching like so will lead to a failed output.

```
test(flag? new String[]{str1}: new String[]{str1, str2, str3});
```

Since test expects a string array as output.
But compilation is successfull since both of them are string arrays.

Way 5

```
test(flag? str1: str2);
```

This is where my earlier reasoning of test expecting a String[] fails. 
But even though compilation will be successful, you wouldn't be getting an output since test is still expecting an array to output.

Comment: Way 3 fails because both expressions of a ternary expression must be of the same type.

Comment: Not if I remember right.
c = true? a : b;
would work even if a was int and b string.

Comment: Autoboxing is fine with primitive types, but with more complex types you will see unexpected results. Do not get into the habit of doing it.

Comment: It just fails for more complex types I guess. Yeah,I don't do it,just said that it isnt always the case.